# Group list item by elements for use in a jsp receipt

Tags: java, hibernate, list, jsp, jakarta-ee

I've some code below as that I use for querying the db and adding data to the list,

```
Query q= session.createQuery("select tally_receipt_prefix, tally_receipt_no,           tally_head, tally_amount from Tally_table where tally_system_date='"+fmtd_date+"' and tally_dbcr_indicator='DB' and tally_mode='Ca' order by  tally_head,tally_receipt_prefix,tally_receipt_no");

    payincash = new ArrayList();

    for(Iterator it=q.iterate(); it.hasNext(); )
    {
        Object[] row= (Object[]) it.next();
        payincash.add((String)row[0]);
        payincash.add((String)row[1]);
        payincash.add((String)row[2]);
        payincash.add((String)row[3]);

    }

    System.out.println("cash list in dao: "+payincash);
```

The list returned looks something like [prefix1, no1, head1, amt1, prefix2, no2, head2, amt2,]. I'm trying to make a receipt in jsp on the lines of

### head1

prefix1/no1 amt1

prefix2/no2 amt 2

---

### head3

prefix3/no3 amt3

So seemingly I want to group all records by head column in the receipt - jsp file. How do I go about this? Any help completely appreciated. Please excuse my English.

Edit: Here is what I tried,

Query q= session.createQuery("select tally_receipt_prefix, tally_receipt_no, tally_head, tally_amount from Tally_table where tally_system_date='"+fmtd_date+"' and tally_dbcr_indicator='DB' and tally_mode='Ca' order by tally_head,tally_receipt_prefix,tally_receipt_no");
        System.out.println("query "+q);

```
    List heads=new ArrayList();

    for(Iterator it=q.iterate(); it.hasNext(); )
    {
        Object[] row= (Object[]) it.next();

        payincash1=new LinkedHashMap<String, List>();

        heads.add((String)row[2]);

        List tails = null;
        tails=new ArrayList();
        tails.add((String)row[0]);
        tails.add((String)row[1]);
        tails.add((String)row[3]);

        System.out.println("heads in dao from iter 1: "+heads);  
        System.out.println("tails in dao from iter1 on: "+tails);

        if(heads.contains((String)row[2]))  // for head in temp list
        {
            System.out.println("in first if");
            if(payincash1.containsKey((String)row[2]))     
            {
                System.out.println("map if repeat: "+payincash1);
                payincash1.put((String)row[2],tails);
            }

        } 
        else
        {

            System.out.println("map if not repeat: "+payincash1);
            payincash1.put((String)row[2], tails);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is the head column of the receipt stored? at what column? 
In my humble opinion it should be stored at the database as well. 
Let's say the head information is kept in column "head" at DB, so you should change your query, by adding:

```
order by head
```

At the end. 
After that, you should iterate over the Result, and maybe keep the information in a data structure that looks like this:

```
Map<String,List<ReceiptInformation> map = new HashMap<>(); //using JDK7 syntax here
```

The key in the map should be the value of "head" in each iteration.
The value in the map should be an ArrayList (or any other class implementing List) that holds ReceiptInfo objects. 
ReceiptInfoObject holds all the rest of the values per record. 
Then, you can iterate on the map.keySet() collection , and for each key, prting the head, and then print the receipts using an internal loop. 
Edited per request of the user who asked the question: 
In order to add new entries (i.e - new RecepitInformation object to the map) one should perform:

```
List<RecepitInformation> listForHead = map.get(headValue);
if (listForHead == null) {
   listForHead = new ArrayList<ReceiptInformation>();
   map.put(headValue,listForHead);
}
listForHead.add(recepitInformation);
```

As usual, I did not compile this, but i think it should work

Comment: Thanks for the response. Head is the third column in the select statement (tally_head). Map<String, List> seems like what I was looking for. But, how do I add the list to the values of the same key - tally_head. Adding value to the same key replaces the old value and I need the list to be appended with information.

Comment: Hi, I will update my answer according to your question, however, I would appreciate an upvote or a mark of correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

With [GS Collections](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections) you can use list.[groupBy](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections/blob/89c103b75260348cb2aa659c9afaa0c600e339a5/collections-api/src/main/java/com/gs/collections/api/RichIterable.java#L791)(Function) as long as your list is a [MutableList](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections/blob/master/collections-api/src/main/java/com/gs/collections/api/list/MutableList.java).  For a JDK list, you could use [Iterate.groupBy](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections/blob/b76f846c6f65bb07ff0704d2ed44b627ff7716ca/collections/src/main/java/com/gs/collections/impl/utility/Iterate.java#L1895)(Iterable, Function).  The result of groupBy will be a [Multimap](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections/blob/master/collections-api/src/main/java/com/gs/collections/api/multimap/Multimap.java).